# Bind() on AF_PACKET socket fails at first ... then fixes itself?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I can't figure this out.
When I run my code ... I see data from all Ethernet types and from all interfaces even though I bind successfuly.
After a couple minutes running ... it fixes itself.
Then I see only from a particular interface and only if the Ether type matches.
The objective is to cycle through all interfaces looking for a particular MAC address.
When the correct response is returned ... we drop out the for loop with all things configured as necessary.

```
// Copyright (c) 2017 Keith M. Bradley
// 
//
// History:
//    13 May 2017 Keith M. Bradley  Creation
//      all rights reserved.
//

/* ----------------------- Standard includes --------------------------------*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <netpacket/packet.h>
#include <netdb.h>



#define     SIGNAL_THREAD_KILL  0xFF
#define     SIGNAL_THREAD_RESET 0xFE

// Ethernet II protocol to use (0x88b5 ... experimental #1).
#define     eType 0x88b5

#define msg_Hello "MikiePLC"
#define msg_Reply "IOM_1.0"
#define msg_Ack   "ackMikiePLC"


void* PLCThread(void* arg)
{
  // get our pointer to the PLC struct
  PLC   *myPLC = arg;
  // get and save our thread ID
  myPLC->tid = pthread_self();
  // thread index number?



  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // locals
  uint8_t i;            // used as an index or loop counts.
  uint8_t j;            // used as 2nd index or loop counts.

  int     rtn;          // temp store or function return values.


  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // create Ethernet buffers and variables.

  char*       outBuff = NULL;  // character buffer for sending out on Ethernet.  
  size_t      outBuffSz = 1540;

  char*       inBuff = NULL;   // character buffer for receiving in on Ethernet. 
  size_t      inBuffSz = 1540;

  int         fd;              // file descriptor for socket.

  int         flags;           // socket flags used bt fcntl().

  struct
  ifreq       ifr;             // used to get and set interface parameters.

  struct
  sockaddr_ll IOM_sa_flt;      // socket address struct, used to filter received Ethernet frames from the remote IO module ... used by bind().

  struct
  sockaddr_ll IOM_sa_rcv;      // socket address struct, used to store addr details of received frame ... used by recvfrom().
  socklen_t   IOM_sa_len;      // IOM_sa_rcv length.

  fd_set      myfds;           // used by select().

  struct
  timeval     rcv_tm_out;      // time out for select() to declare communications failed.



  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // initialize Ethernet buffers and variables.

  // allocate memory for the Ethernet sending message buffer.
  outBuff = malloc(outBuffSz);
  if (outBuff == NULL)
    printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: Could not allocate outBuff memory.");
  memset(outBuff, '\0', outBuffSz);

  // allocate memory for the Ethernet recevied message buffer.
  inBuff = malloc(inBuffSz);
  if (inBuff == NULL)
    printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: Could not allocate inBuff memory.");

  // clear the sockaddr_ll structs.
  // (send was already cleared ... it is inside the PLC typdef).
  memset(&IOM_sa_rcv, 0, sizeof(IOM_sa_rcv));
  memset(&IOM_sa_flt, 0, sizeof(IOM_sa_flt));

  // set receiving sockaddr_ll struct size.
  IOM_sa_len = sizeof(IOM_sa_rcv);

  // setup the sending, receiving, and filtering sockaddr_ll's.
  myPLC->IOM_sa_snd.sll_family    = AF_PACKET;
  myPLC->IOM_sa_snd.sll_protocol  = htons(eType);

  IOM_sa_rcv.sll_family    = AF_PACKET;
  IOM_sa_rcv.sll_protocol  = htons(eType);

  IOM_sa_flt.sll_family    = AF_PACKET;
  IOM_sa_flt.sll_protocol  = htons(eType);



  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // open our socket in dgram mode and setup the socket's features.
  fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
  if (fd == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
    printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: socket() failed !! - ");
  }

  // get the socket file descriptor flags.
  flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);

  // if succesful, set to non-blocking.
  if (flags != -1)
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);




  if (fd != -1) // valid socket file descriptor means ok to proceed with IOM_Addr_search.
  {
    // IOM_MAC_search
    //   if MAC_Addr is configured, 
    //   loop to find which interface has the IOM (I/O Module).
    //
    // begin for loop ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (i = 1; 1; i++)
    {
      // we need to test for thread kill signal.
      if((myPLC->ThreadCtrl == SIGNAL_THREAD_KILL) || (myPLC->ThreadCtrl == SIGNAL_THREAD_RESET)) break;

      // if the user cleared the MAC addr while we were searching ... give up and run the engine. 
      if (myPLC->MAC_is_Valid != 0xa5) break;

      // clear the ifreq struct.
      memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));

      // i is our 'for' loop counter and our current interface index.
      ifr.ifr_ifindex = i;

      // does the interface exist?
      if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFNAME, &ifr) == -1)
      {
        // if not, we ran past top of network interfaces.
        printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_MAC_search MAC address not found after searching all interfaces !!!\n");
        printf("\n_________________________________________________________________________________________\n");
        sleep(10);
        i = 0;
        continue;
      }
      // don't mess with loopback interface.
      if (strcmp(ifr.ifr_name,"lo") == 0) continue;

      // store the ifname using the pointer.
      strncpy (myPLC->ifName, ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name) - 1);
      myPLC->ifName[IFNAMSIZ - 1] = '\0';

      // update the interface index in all sockaddr structs.
      myPLC->IOM_sa_snd.sll_ifindex = i;
      IOM_sa_rcv.sll_ifindex = i;
      IOM_sa_flt.sll_ifindex = i;

      // is the interface up?
      ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr);
      if ((ifr.ifr_flags & IFF_UP) == 0)
      {
        printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search interface %s (index %d) is down.\n", myPLC->ifName, i);
        continue;
      }

      // bind it.
      if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&IOM_sa_flt, sizeof(IOM_sa_flt)) == -1)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search bind() failed  !!!\n");
        continue;
      }

      // pause and flush? (didn't help at all)
      sleep(2);
      recvfrom(fd, inBuff, inBuffSz, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&IOM_sa_rcv, &IOM_sa_len);

      // fill outBuff with the hello message.
      strcpy(outBuff, msg_Hello);

      // send hello msg to the IOM with configured IOM_MAC_address.
      if (sendto(fd, outBuff, sizeof(msg_Hello), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&(myPLC->IOM_sa_snd), sizeof (myPLC->IOM_sa_snd)) == -1)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search sendto() failed on interface %s (index %d) !!!\n", myPLC->ifName, i);
        continue;
      }

      // setup for the select() time out loop.
      rcv_tm_out.tv_sec = 0;
      rcv_tm_out.tv_usec = 50000;

      // begin while loop ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      //
      // select() time out loop.
      //   wait for valid response from IOM_MAC_address (discard any ETHERNET 2 messages from other MAC's).
      //
      while ((rcv_tm_out.tv_sec != 0) || (rcv_tm_out.tv_usec != 0))
      {
        // create the file descriptor set for use by select().
        FD_ZERO(&myfds);
        FD_SET(fd, &myfds);

        // select() to sleep until received frame is ready, or the maximum length of time it would taked to get a response is exceeded.
        rtn = select(fd + 1, &myfds, NULL, NULL, &rcv_tm_out);
        if (rtn < 0)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
          printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search select() returned <0 on interface %s (index %d).\n", myPLC->ifName, i);
          break;
        }
        // did we time out? ... then goto the next interface to search.
        else if (rtn == 0)
        {
          printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search select() timed out (returned 0) on interface %s (index %d).\n", myPLC->ifName, i);
          break;
        }
        else  // select() returned > 0.
        {
          if (FD_ISSET(fd, &myfds))
          {
            // our socket is ready for reading ... 1st clear the buffer and the sock addr.
            memset(inBuff, '\0', inBuffSz);
            for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
              IOM_sa_rcv.sll_addr[j] = 0;
            rtn = recvfrom(fd, inBuff, inBuffSz, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&IOM_sa_rcv, &IOM_sa_len);
            if(rtn < 0)
            {
              if (errno == EAGAIN)
                printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search recvfrom() returned EAGAIN.\n");
              else if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
                printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search recvfrom() returned EWOULDBLOCK.\n");
              else
              {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
                printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search recvfrom() returned unrecoverable error.\n");
              }
              break;
            }
            else if (rtn == 0)
              printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search a_file_descriptor_is_set yet recvfrom() returned zero.\n");
            else  // recvfrom() returned > 0.
            {
              printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search recvfrom() returned %d bytes on %s (index %d) MAC %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x   rcv_tm_out.tv_sec = %d.%d\n",
                                                                                                                                                rtn,
                                                                                                                                                myPLC->ifName,
                                                                                                                                                i,
                                                                                                                                                IOM_sa_rcv.sll_addr[0],
                                                                                                                                                IOM_sa_rcv.sll_addr[1],
                                                                                                                                                IOM_sa_rcv.sll_addr[2],
                                                                                                                                                IOM_sa_rcv.sll_addr[3],
                                                                                                                                                IOM_sa_rcv.sll_addr[4],
                                                                                                                                                IOM_sa_rcv.sll_addr[5],
                                                                                                                                                (int)rcv_tm_out.tv_sec,
                                                                                                                                                (int)rcv_tm_out.tv_usec);
              // check the IOM_sa_rcv.MAC_Addr ... is it who we want to talk to? ... if not discard.
              for (j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
                if ((myPLC->IOM_sa_snd.sll_addr[j]) == (IOM_sa_rcv.sll_addr[j])) continue;

              // MAC addr matches?
              if (j > 50) // set to 50 to debug ... should be 5.
              {
                printf("\nMAC Addr from our IOM.\n");
                // parse the received response to our hello msg.
                if (strcmp(inBuff, msg_Reply) == 0)
                {
                  // fill outBuff with the Ack message.
                  strcpy(outBuff, msg_Ack);
                  // send ack message to the IOM with configured IOM_MAC_address.
                  if (sendto(fd, outBuff, sizeof("ackMikiePLC"), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&(myPLC->IOM_sa_snd), sizeof (myPLC->IOM_sa_snd)) == -1)
                 {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
                    printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search sendto() failed on interface %s (index %d) !!!\n", myPLC->ifName, i);
                    continue;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    // declare ComStatus ok.
                    myPLC->ComStatus = 0xa5;
                    break;  // we have a winner !!!
                  }
                }
                else
                {
                  // declare ComStatus still NOT ok.
                  myPLC->ComStatus = 0x5a;
                  continue;
                }
              }
              else
              {
                printf("\nMAC Addr from a stranger (discarded)!!!\n");
                break;
              }
            }// END recvfrom() returned > 0.
          }// END if (FD_ISSET(fd, &myfds))
          else printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search select() returned > 0 yet our only file descriptor was not set !!!\n");
        }// END select() returned > 0.
      }// END while loop -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      if (myPLC->ComStatus == 0xa5) break;  // search is done ... break out of for loop.
    }// END for loop -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }// END "valid socket fd means ok to proceed" ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  else printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search socket() previously failed ... search cannot proceed.\n");





  // MAIN ENGINE LOOP !!!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //
  // Loop for the life of this Sedona PLC object (unless Enable is false).
  //
  while((myPLC->ThreadCtrl != SIGNAL_THREAD_KILL) && (myPLC->ThreadCtrl != SIGNAL_THREAD_RESET))
  {

  }



  CleanExit: //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  close(fd);
  free(outBuff);
  free(inBuff);
  free(myPLC);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Here is a print example when it starts:

NATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search recvfrom() returned 104 bytes on eth0 (index 2) MAC 00:1e:c9:7d:c4:36   rcv_tm_out.tv_sec = 0.49997

MAC Addr from a stranger !!!

NATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_Addr_search recvfrom() returned 152 bytes on enp1s0 (index 3) MAC 00:1e:c9:7d:c4:36   rcv_tm_out.tv_sec = 0.49998

MAC Addr from a stranger !!!

NATIVE-PLCThread: IOM_MAC_search MAC address not found after searching all interfaces !!!

---

I should see "select() timed out" on eth0 since there is nothing responding with Ether type 0x88b5.

Comment: What's the return code from `bind()`?

Comment: not -1 so I assume 0? Docs say zero on success ... -1 or error.

Comment: Ah, apologis. What's the value of `errno` on failure?

Comment: it never print's ... the bracketed code under bind never runs ... so I assume there is no error?

Comment: regarding: `outBuff = malloc(outBuffSz);
  if (outBuff == NULL)
    printf("\nNATIVE-PLCThread: Could not allocate outBuff memory.");
  memset(outBuff, '\0', outBuffSz);`  1) when the call to `malloc()` fails, DO NOT EVER try to use the returned value (it is NULL)  2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest using `perror()` rather than `printf()` and should also output the OS text that is associated with the error.  `perror()` outputs the enclosed text and the OS text to `stderr`  3) generally, when a call to `malloc()` fails, the program needs to exited.

Comment: Thanks user3629249 !! I needed to clean that up at some point.

Comment: regarding: `if (flags != -1)
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);  if (fd != -1)`  This is NOT the time to be checking `fd`.  rather the code should look similar to: `if (flags != -1) {
    int fcntlStat; if( (fcntlStat =fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) )  != 0 ) { perror( "fcntl to set non blocking attribute failed" ); // cleanup then exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); } }`

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 1; 1; i++)`  this loop will never terminate.  the variable `i` will continue to be incremented until is becomes negative and eventually loops back to the original value.  Please explain, in an edit to your question, exactly what the code is trying to accomplish.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: the question is about a run time problem, but the posted code is missing almost everything needed for a clean compile. Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the problem.

I created the socket with ETH_P_ALL.
I assumed I could be more specific in the bind as the docs say we can.

Preliminary test so far has not reproduced the issue.

I have seen many sources that say one can do what I originally did ... so this may be a bug in Linux or the driver?

Comment: Yes ... after several runs ... problem is gone.